# Nested for loop c#

Tags: c#

I have a school project and I need to complete it but its not working. I have to do a nested for loop in c# , I have managed to do the earlier projects which had the result :
1 2 3 6

1 2 3 6

1 2 3 6

1 2 3 6

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            int x = 1;
            int y = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
            {             
                Console.Write(x);
                y = y + x;
                x = x + 1;   
            }   
            Console.Write(y);
            Console.WriteLine(); 
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

but now i stuck with the second project which must give an output :

1 2 3 6
2 3 4 9
3 4 5 12
5 6 7 18

please help anyone !!

Comment: I would actually go to your instructor and tell that you do not understand the assignment. This is not a code factory site best I can say if start using the debugger and understand what the requirements are we are not here to do your homework for you..

Comment: I suspect you are missing some simple arithmetic logic.  very hard to help if we dont know how those sequences are arrived at.

Comment: This is more a problem of figuring out or identifying the algorithm or rule that governs the sequence, than a coding issue. The code is fine, you just need to figure out or generate a rule that will produce those values.  The first three rows are easy, they are just the values in the prior row plus 1 for the first three columns, and plus 3 for the last column. The 4th row is row 3 plus 2 for columns 1-3, and plus 6 for the last column.  you can implement this in your loops in any number of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++)
{
   if (x == 4) x = 5;
   Console.Write("{0} ",x);
   for (var y = 1; y < 4; y++)
       Console.Write("{0} ", y < 3 ? x + y : 3 * (x + 1));
   Console.WriteLine();      
}
```

EXPLANATION:

required output is:

```
1 2 3 6
2 3 4 9
3 4 5 12
5 6 7 18
```

So here are four rows and four columns
first column in each row is 1,2,3,5, so outer loop in x goes from 1 to 4, and first statement changes the last value of 4 to a 5.
The 2nd & 3rd columns are always just the first column incremented by one, then by one again, and finally, last 4th column is 3 times 1 + the first column. So inner loop in y just goes 1, 2, 3, and, for 2nd and 3rd column, prints the first column plus the y value (1, 2) for 2nd and 3rd column and three times 1 plus the first column for the last (4th) column.

So each row is, effectively
x, x+1, x+2, 3*(x+1)

and each row starts with x one greater than the row before it, except we skip row 4

The expression `y < 3 ? x + y : 3 * (x + 1)` is a ternary which has three parts, a Boolean condition, followed by a question mark (?), the value to generate when the Boolean is true, followed by a colon (:) and then the value to generate when the Boolean is false. So it reads like this:

if y is less than 3, output x+y, else output 3 times (x+1)

Another simpler option (which only uses one loop), might be:

```
for (var x = 2; x < 7; x++)
{
   if (x == 5) continue; // skip row 4
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} ",x-1, x, x+1, 3*x);            
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you . but still need to understand this code its a little complicated @CharlesBretana

Comment: First time I've had an answer score -2 and be picked as winner

Comment: thank you so much that was really helpfull .

Answer (score -1):

Well, here is the solution for you. But please try to understand it and next time you wont ask us to solve your homework.

```
int p;
for (int x = 1; x < 6; x++)
{
  if (x !== 4)
  {
    for (int y = x; y < x + 3; y++)
    {
      p += y;
      Console.Write(y);
    }     
    Console.Write(p);
    Console.WriteLine(); 
    p = 0;
  }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I made it a little different, so you can play with it.

Comment: What do you expect to see on console after executing `Console.Write(p);`

Comment: Well, you moved `p = 0;.` down.

Comment: thank you , but still the last number in the row is not what i want it to be .

Comment: ok, updated my answer.